# Nested Resources Post Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application that has two scaffolds (that are the same as the default you generate). I have a routes.rb that looks like this:

```
resources :companies do
   resources :peoples
end
```

Until I added the nested routes, the two scaffolds worked perfectly alone. But when I added the nested routes, when I visit a route like:

```
http://localhost:3000/companies/bobs-pizza/peoples/new
```

and fill out the peoples form and submit, I get an error like:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/companies/bobs-pizza/peoples/new"
```

my _form.html.erb for the peoples scaffold ( the child in the relationship between peoples and companies) I changed to look like this:

```
<%= form_for companies_path(@company,@people) do |f| %>
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Lets say Bobs-pizza has an id of 1, you probably should visit `/localhost:3000/companies/1/peoples/new` . That is my first thought where the mistake might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run rake routes and ensure that companies_path is the correct route you need.

Comment: If not form for [@company, @people] might work but I'm not near a computer and my rails is rusty :) it might just be fore scopes and namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for there is an example of form_for with associations:

> If your resource has associations defined, for example, you want to add comments to [a] document...

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Where:

```
@document = Document.find(params[:id])
```

and

```
@comment = Comment.new
```

I think the named route would be something like:

```
company_peoples_path(@company)
```

By the way, if you have a model named People, what fields does a people have?